# Run pentaho jobs from database postgres

Tags: postgresql, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I am using the community version of pentaho 7.0. I have a repository in a db postgres but I don't know how to schedule a task executing the jobs directly from the repository. I can only do it with pan.bat or kitchen.bat from a local path.
Can you help me please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually create a BAT file and then schedule it by task scheduler.
Below is a sample which I use for the BAT File.

```
C:\data-integration\Kitchen.bat"/rep:"TEST" /job:"TEST_JOB" /dir:/TEST /user:admin /pass:admin
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to write a shell script or batch script and schedule it through crontab or windows Scheduler.Use the below links for Linux and Windows Scheduler.
https://linuxize.com/post/scheduling-cron-jobs-with-crontab/
https://windowsreport.com/schedule-tasks-windows-10/